# How to return the value of promise by using executeAsyncScript callback function

Tags: javascript, java, webdriver

I am trying to fetch some data from webdriver which are generated by JS code.
Java code:

```
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String script = Files.toString(new File("./JsLib/dist/RunScan.js"), Charsets.UTF_8);
    Object result = jse.executeAsyncScript(script);
```

RunScan.js file:

```
var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
Evaluator.runScan().then((results) => { callback(results); } );
```

The Evaluator.runScan() method returns a Promise object:

```
public runScan(): Promise<Map<String, Requirement>> {
        return new Promise<Map<String, Requirement>>((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
            this.evaluateDocument().then(() => {
                this.assessRequirements().then(() => {
                    resolve(this._requirements);
                }, (error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
            }, (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    }
```

When I run the java code, it complains:

```
> Testcase: testWithJS took 39.338 sec
>     [junit]   Caused an ERROR
>     [junit] Timed out waiting for async script result after 30159ms
>     [junit] Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
>     [junit] System info: host: 'WIN-6I10A27G9QR', ip: '10.1.78.28', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2',
> java.version: '1.8.0_73'
>     [junit] Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I have tried different timeout values like 5 second, 3 minutes or 10 minutes, but does not work. I think there is something wrong with the callback function part. I have searched a lot online, but can not resolve it. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Need to see more of your code to understand how the error is occuring..

Comment: how exactly do you build the callback function out of the `arguments`?

Comment: @MaxG The callback function is a default argument when you use executeAsyncScript and it is always the last one. From what I learned,  for executing a async js code, this is the only way I can get the data.

Comment: @Remixt What code do you need? I just pasted part of the runScan code which return a promise object and the value should be a Map.